# What is exactly happening when you're Docker Commiting a container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I know that when you use, for example, `docker commit abcdefgh ola/minhaimagem:1.0`  you are saving your changes from the **abcdefgh** container into a new image to use it again futurely. However, i noticed that sometimes the commit runs very slow and that fact arised the question in my mind, what does exactly is happening while the commit is running? I mean, what is happening under the hood?

Comment: Note to maintainers: this is a Stack Overflow question, and has nothing to do with Server Fault.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [`docker commit`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/2cd8b876ad1c235ccd932d101252423fa86aee06/docs/reference/commandline/commit.md):

> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be paused while the image is committed. This reduces the likelihood of encountering data corruption during the process of creating the commit.

That step (waiting for the processes to pause) can take time.

> If this behavior is undesired, set the `--pause` option to false.

You can see the actual commit call in [`api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#postCommit()`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/020a86b3d9e6b052a3f866b7517eb0f62fd24bea/api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#L48-L61) which is then routed through a backend to [`daemon/commit.go#Commit()`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ce255f76c70a77c21d48ebd407d83cad55edf883/daemon/commit.go#L121)

Comment: Maybe more pertinent context for the question is "I committed a docker container state recently and it only took ~5 seconds.  Now my commit is taking > 2 minutes; why is this the case?

Comment: In my case, I did generate an anaconda environment, number of images, and .json files in the container, but I saw that the disk usage only went from ~33% last time to ~44% this time

Comment: After considering this for a bit, I realize it would probably be easier to learn how to automate this in the Dockerfile so all the details of the conda installations don't slow everything down.  I read one of your other answers stating that's best practice

Comment: @Nathan Yes, that is the idea. Don't forget a multistage build; it could help in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254461/6309