# Docker multistage build without copying from previous image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

does it have any advantages to use a multistage build in Docker, if you don't copy any files from the previously built image?
eg.

```
FROM some_base_image as base
#Some random commands
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app2
RUN mkdir /app3
#ETC

#Second stage starts from first stage
FROM base

#Add some files to image
COPY  foo.txt /app
```

Does this result in a smaller image or offer any other advantages compared to a non multi-stage version? Or are multi stage builds only useful for preparing some files and then copying those into another base image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or are multi stage builds only useful for preparing some files and then copying those into another base image?

This is  the main use-case discussed in "[Use multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)"

The main goal is to reduce the number of layers by copying files from one image to another, without including the build environment needed to produce said files.

But, another goal could be *not* rebuild the entire Dockerfile including every stage.

Then your suggestion (not copying) could still apply.

> You can specify a target build stage. The following command assumes you are using the previous Dockerfile but stops at the stage named builder:
>
> ```
> $ docker build --target builder -t alexellis2/href-counter:latest .
> ```
>
> A  few scenarios where this might be very powerful are:
>
> - Debugging a specific build stage
> - Using a `debug` stage with all debugging symbols or tools enabled, and a lean `production` stage
> - Using a `testing` stage in which your app gets populated with test data, but building for `production` using a different stage which uses real data

Comment: `But, another goal could be not rebuild the entire Dockerfile including every stage.` But the docker build is already cached, i.e. by checking the checksums of the files you use and comparing the text of the run commands. So that seems not a good use case. Especially since you normally want a rebuild if an external file changes.

Comment: Also it appears the link you provided is broken? Was it this one [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)?

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the link. The key part was 'The following command assumes you are using the previous Dockerfile but stops at the stage named builder:'. Meaning you don't have to docker build all your Dockerfile, but you can docker build stage by stage, incrementally.